# in this case is better ng-hide/show or ng-if?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using Angular with Ionic on my application, I am having some issues with the `ng-show` so I decided to change and put `ng-if` instead, and now my app is working as I want, but I have some doubts. What about performance ? and is correctly what I am doing ?

this is how I have my code now:

```
        <div ng-if="betSlip.length >= 1">
          <div class="list betslip-item">
            <div class="item item-divider betslip-header">
              APPLY TO ALL
            </div>
```

and this is how I had it:

```
        <div ng-show="betSlip.length >= 1">
          <div class="list betslip-item">
            <div class="item item-divider betslip-header">
              APPLY TO ALL
            </div>
```

**Update**

What about `ng-switch`?

Comment: this is an example of the XY problem.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378.  Instead of asking if the possible solution has performance issues, start with asking about or explaining what your issues are with `ng-show`

Comment: On a side note, if you want the `ngShow` to work, wrap it around curly braces `{{betSlip.length >= 1}}` as it evaluates it as an expression

Comment: and what about ```ng-switch```? @RSquared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng-show/hide merely applies display:none style to your component, but the DOM element is still there, and is still there, ng-if on the other hand, creates the DOM element only if the condition is met, wether is better ng-if or show dependes on some factors, how often/fast is the condition switched, is this based on user interaction or on a very fast changing computational calculation?, also, how many bindings does your switched element has?

this is my criteria for when to use over the other

```
1 if the container is simple(none, or few bindings) and my dom is not too crowded already and doesn't have required fields or is not contained inside a form  i am ok using hide/show 
2 if my element contains a lot of bindings, my DOM is aleady extense, or the existance of the the content affects some how the result of the application ie(required fields or submit buttons inside a form) then i use ng-if or ng-switch
```

those are not documented but is my choice of handling dom insertions/display

Comment: and what about ```ng-switch```?

Comment: ng-switch and ng-if are simillar in functionllity ng-switch allows to "switch" content by creating and deleting the elements based on condition